# Getting 0.00 decimal value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query in SQL Server,

```
SELECT
    SUM(issue_count) AS incent_issued, 
    SUM(redeem_count) AS incent_redeemed,
    CAST(SUM(redeem_count) / NULLIF(SUM(issue_count), 0) AS decimal(18, 2)) AS incent_redemption_rate
FROM
    incent_summary
```

I get the following output:

```
incent_issued   incent_redeemed incent_redemption_rate
-------------------------------------------------------
53742                  7205            0.00
```

Why am I getting `incent_redemption_rate` as 0.00? I am expecting it to be 0.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division, so `1/2` is `0`, not `0.5`.  I find that the simplest solution is to multiply by `1.0`:

```
SUM(redeem_count) * 1.0/NULLIF(SUM(issue_count), 0)
```

Note that you are converting to a decimal *after* the division, so that conversion has no effect on the integer division.